# Linker warning when building CUDA C++ code in debug mode using VS2022

Tags: c++, cuda

I created a project in Visual Studio 2022 using the CUDA 11.7 project template and built it in Debug x64 mode. There is a linker warning "LINK: warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library".

The warning wouldn't go away for both /MTd and /MDd.

How do I overcome this?

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-warning-lnk4098?view=msvc-170

For /MTd, these libraries need to be ignored: libcmt.lib; msvcrt.lib; msvcrtd.lib.
For /MDd, these libraries need to be ignored: libcmt.lib; msvcrt.lib; libcmtd.lib.

/MTd and /MDd can specified in Project Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library

Libraries to be ignored can be specified in Project Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Ignore Specific Default Libraries